# java progaram for permutations of two inputs, one string and one integer

Tags: java, permutation

hi i need a java progaram of permutation and combinations of two inputs one string and one integer.

Ex:- if we give string as "abcd" and give second inputs as 2 then output should be as {ab,ac,ad,ba,bc,bd,ca,cb,cd,da,db,dc} if we give second input as 3 then combinations should be like {abc,abd,bad,bcd,cab,cbd.........}

this is what i have tried

```
package aaa;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {



    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the string whose permutations we need to show ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String original=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("enter number");
        int n=in.nextInt();
             System.out.println("Results are :");
             for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                 permute1(original,n);

            }

    }
    public static   void permute1( String input, int x)
    {        
        StringBuffer outputString = new StringBuffer();
        String input1 = input.substring(0,x-1); 
        int input1Length = input1.length();
        boolean[ ] used1 = new boolean[ input1Length ];
                char[ ] in = input1.toCharArray( );

        doPermute ( in, outputString, used1, input1Length, 0 );

    }

    public static    void doPermute ( char[ ] in, StringBuffer outputString,
    boolean[ ] used, int inputLength, int level)
    {
        if( level == inputLength) {
            System.out.println ( outputString.toString());
            return;
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < inputLength; ++i )
        {

            if( used[i] ) continue;

            outputString.append( in[i] );
            used[i] = true;
            doPermute( in,   outputString, used, inputLength, level + 1 );
            used[i] = false;
            outputString.setLength(   outputString.length() - 1 );

        }
    }


}
```

help me with suggestions

Comment: Welcome to SO. And what is exactly the problem with what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Permutation {
    static int c;
    List<String> permutations = new LinkedList<String>();
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); 
    String input =sc.nextLine();
    int conbinationSize = sc.nextInt();
    boolean[] isChoosed = new boolean[input.length()];
    public void generateCombination(String partialOutput) {
        if (partialOutput.length() == conbinationSize) {
            permutations.add(partialOutput);
            c++;
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
            if (!isChoosed[i]) {
                isChoosed[i] = true;
                generateCombination(partialOutput + input.charAt(i));
                isChoosed[i] = false;      
            }
        }
    }

    void printCombination() {
        for (String c : permutations) {
            System.out.println(c);         
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Permutation dfs = new Permutation();
        dfs.generateCombination("");
        dfs.printCombination();
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```